# Check for equality against multiple values in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I am looking for an easy, fast and descriptive way in C++ to check if a value is contained in a fixed set of other values.  Like in Python, where one can write

```
if some_function() in (2, 3, 5, 7, 11):
    do_something()
```

Some obvious options are:

1. `switch`/`case`: If the values in question are integers, then one can write something like this:

   ```
   switch (some_function()) {
       case 2: case 3: case 5: case 7: case 11: do_something();
   }
   ```

   Unfortunately, this only works for integers, and I daresay it's not very pretty.
2. Use a local variable to keep the temporary result:

   ```
   const auto x = some_function();
   if (x == 2 || x == 3 || x == 5 || x == 7 || x == 11) do_something();
   ```

   I would like to avoid the named temporary variable.  Furthermore, this is tedious to write and error-prone.
3. Use `std::set`: This can be written (at least in C++20) as:

   ```
   if (std::set({ 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 }).contains(some_function())) do_something();
   ```

   That's kinda nice, but I fear it has some heavy STL overhead.

Are there other, cheaper methods?  Maybe some variadic template solution?

Comment: Option 3 is appropriate. Don't dismiss it on account of performance unless it really is a bottleneck in testing.

Comment: I like your update with the benchmarks. However, that shouldn't really be part of the question. Instead, post that as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can indeed write a variadic template function, combined with a fold-expression, like this:

```
namespace my 
{
  template<typename T, typename ... Vals>
  bool any_of(T t, Vals ...vals)
  {
     return (... || (t == vals));
  }
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
if (my::any_of(some_function(), 2, 3, 5, 7, 11))
{
    do_something();
}
```

---

Note that I've put `any_of` in a namespace so as to avoid any confusion with `std::any_of` which is a completely different function.

Comment: That is super-sweet, merci! Just to make one thing clear: that is *not* `std::any_of`, but a self-made template.

Comment: @cxxl Yes, absolutely :)

Comment: I took the liberty to rename the template, so it is more readily usable and doesn't clash with `std::any_of`.

Comment: @cxxl No, that's not a good idea. There's no reason to clash with `std::any_of` unless you bring in the namespace `std`, which you shouldn't be doing anyway. Instead, put this function inside another namespace, e.g. `my`, and then explicitly qualify it `my::any_of`. That's a much better option.

Comment: @cxxl If my previous comment makes sense, then go ahead and edit my answer to show that option. Otherwise, I'll edit it. Either way, I definitely don't want to change the name from `any_of` to another name just because there's a function in `std` with that name.

Comment: @cxxl Edited. Does that make sense now?

Comment: Now we're both happy. :)

Answer (score 2):

Some data on the `fast` part of the question:

I compiled the three obvious solutions and the one by @cigien with Visual Studio 2019 (C++ Compiler 19.27.29122) with full optimizations (`/Ox /std:c++latest`) and looked at the assembler output. Here is what I found:

1. This solution turns into a sweet `BT` instruction (x64) or a jump table (x86), both only some 10 lines of assembler.
2. Again a `BT` instruction (x64) or the obvious 5 comparisons in a row (x86), again about 10 lines.
3. Speedwise, this is the horror: 120 lines with 9 calls to other functions, all in all 1500 (!) lines. Plus, it requires exceptions and C++20.
4. @cigien's solution: the same as 2. for both x64 and x86.

Bottom line: the template version is not only short and expressive, but also small and fast.

Comment: Much better, thanks :) Standard disclaimer for benchmarks, make sure to compile with optimizations turned on. Also, you could try [quick-bench](https://quick-bench.com/) which is a convenient site to compare the performance of some pieces of code.

Comment: yeah, forgot about `-O3` .  if we're talking about school stuff with 5 elems array then perf will be close

Answer (score 0):

if it's about style all this stuff has nothing to do with c/c++ anyway.
if it's about performance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int b[] = {1 ,4 ,7 ,8};
    int c = 4;
    bool e = std::any_of(std::execution::par, b, &b[0] + sizeof(b)/sizeof(int), [=](int a){ return a == c; });
    if (e) std::cout << "cool " << std::endl;
}
```

`c++ -O3 --std=c++17 a.cpp -o t -ltbb`

Comment: Why are you passing the 3rd argument like that? Why not just `begin` and `end`?

Comment: it will load all hw threads at once.  because b is not a vec

Comment: I meant, why not `std::any_of(std::execution::par, std::begin(b), std::end(b), ...` instead?

Comment: you can use it . I prefer mine

Comment: Sure, that's fine. It was just a suggestion, since I personally find that easier to read :)

Comment: I find this solution hard to read. Furthermore, it will only play out its speed advantage if you compare against a very large set of values.

Comment: sorry but my bet is on that you're unable to really read template from the other answer (for now). may be you meant it's hard to copy-paste

Comment: @cigien say if we have C string `&b[0] + strlen(b)`  will be better than `std::end(b) - 1`

Comment: Multithreading is not a universal solution for speed. Due to thread creation overhead and message passing it can actually be slower for many cases. Bench it.

Comment: Yes, but you don't have a C string, so why write that code?

Comment: @cigien which is to say , for those who can't read this there're vectors . so why to use c++ at all then? vector stuff you're talking about isn't c/c++ concept

Comment: And most likely array is preallocated with some size , so `std::end(b)` will not be related to anything.