# Print of vowels in a string

Tags: c++

I attempted to create a program that let's the user input a string of text and then create a subprogram that will print out all the vowels in that string. The problem with my program is that it only prints out the text once again.

So my terminal will look like:

```
Enter text: Feye
Feye
```

Instead of what I intend it to do:

```
Enter text: Feye
eye
```

This is my code and I wonder what's wrong of it. Why doesn't it print out the index like I ordered it to do in my if-statement?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void print_vowels (string const & text)  
{
    for (int i {}; i < text.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (text.at(i) == 'a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u' || 'y')
        {
            cout << text.at(i);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    string text {};
    
    cout << "Enter text: ";
    getline(cin,text);
    
    print_vowels(text);

    return 0;
}
```

I have also tried putting `text[i]` instead of `text.at(i)` but I get the same results unfortunately.

Comment: `text.at(i) == 'a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u' || 'y'` this doesn't do what think it should.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11583592, https://stackoverflow.com/q/15181579

Comment: Dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43484761

Comment: I don't understand how it is a duplication @Ch3steR. The question you are referring to states if a string is equal to a certain text. This is not what I have asked. I want to look at each and every single index of the string and see if it is equal to something. I don't want to check the whole string at once. Please tell me how it is a "duplication" so I can improve

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ multiple strings inside an if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43484761/c-multiple-strings-inside-an-if-statement)

Comment: Please see below a detailed answer with a very detailed explanations and some further solution proposals

Comment: @drescherjm Do you think we can write something like `if (letter.at(i), in { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' }) . . .`?

Comment: Not the same syntax however this answer has a few options: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64699393/check-for-equality-against-multiple-values-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64699393/check-for-equality-against-multiple-values-in-c)

Comment: @Ch3steR You comment is absolutely correct. Totally true. Very good. But the more interesting question is: Do many people know what will be evaluated here? Very interesting. See below . . .

Comment: @ArminMontigny Thanks for the very detailed answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <array>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>


static constexpr std::array<char, 12> vowels { 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y',
                                               'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y' };

bool is_vowel( const char ch )
{
    return ( std::end( vowels ) != std::find( begin( vowels ),
                                              end( vowels ), ch ) );
}

bool is_consonant( const char ch )
{
    if ( ( ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z' ) ||
         ( ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z' ) )
    {
        return ( std::end( vowels ) == std::find( begin( vowels ),
                                                  end( vowels ), ch ) );
    }

    return false;

}

void print_vowels( const std::string_view text )
{
    for ( const char ch : text )
    {
        if ( is_vowel( ch ) ) { std::cout << ch; }
    }
}

void print_consonants( const std::string_view text )
{
    for ( const char ch : text )
    {
        if ( is_consonant( ch ) ) { std::cout << ch; }
    }
}


int main( )
{
    std::string text { };

    std::cout << "Enter text: ";
    std::getline( std::cin, text );

    std::cout << "vowels: ";
    print_vowels( text );

    std::cout << "\nconsonants: ";
    print_consonants( text );
}
```

Also, note that `at` member function has a performance hit since it also checks for out-of-range indices at run-time. So it's better to use the `[]` operator or a *range-based for-loop* in this case.

Sample input/output:

```
Enter text: Feye
vowels: eye
consonants: F
```

Another sample:

```
Enter text: Apple
vowels: Ae
consonants: ppl
```

Another one:

```
Enter text: Or#an.ge(-=
vowels: Oae
consonants: rng
```

Read about `std::find` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

Comment: I was also thinking, what if I want to create another subprogram that types out the constants in the inputted word? Do I need to do the same thing for every single letter in the alphabet (except the vowels)? Isn't there a faster way to do it?

Like looping through the entire alphabet and if it isn't a vowel, you type out a constant.

Comment: @Mohamed Alkalam I could not quite understand what you mean by *subprogram*. Do you mean a function?

Comment: @digito_evo he just meant another program to identify the constants

Comment: Yeah, a function. My bad

Comment: @Mohamed Alkalam Check the updated answer.

Comment: There are much faster solutions available. Please see my answer. Please also consider the anser of Pepijn Kramer. A `std::unordered_set` together with the `count` function would be the idiomatic correct approach. But, as always, there are many many different possible solutions and yours is good.

Comment: @Armin Montigny I don't think a **compile-time evaluated and sorted stack-based array** can be beaten by a *heap-allocated unordered set* in this particular case. The differences are obvious. Also, the `std::array` has contiguous memory meanwhile the unordered set does not. IMO, any associative container is just too overkill and unnecessary for this particular use case of the OP's question. Anyways, it's hard to prove these things without doing some tests and benchmarks. My opinion is just an opinion (not to be considered as a fact).

Comment: I am very sorry that I need to disappoint you. Your answer is really very very good. But, please see the benchmark at the end of my post. Your solution is even outperformed by the naive approach by 200%. The reason is that not the compile time `std::array` is relevant, but the used search function. Again. you provided a very good answer. And for this use case it doesn't matter anyway. So, good!

Comment: @Armin Montigny I checked the results. Your technique is indeed faster. However, it matters only when it comes to doing dozens of millions of checks (200+ million in your test case). In the OP's use case, the difference might be less than 500 microseconds. And code readability is more important so I myself would choose the unordered set implementation which is both fast and readable.

Answer (score 3):

Some answers are already given. Anyway. I would like to show to you the background and some alternative solutions.

Let us first check your attempt. You were writing:

```
if (text.at(i) == 'a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u' || 'y')
```

And hoping that the letter at index I would be compared to all mentioned letters. But this will not happen. Why?

An `if`-statement expects a Boolean expression. This expression will be evaluated. If the result is equal to true, then the statement or compound statement after the `if` is executed. OK, then let us look at the expression that must be evaluated:

```
text.at(i) == 'a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u' || 'y'
```

consists of operands and operators. Operators have properties. One of them is the precedence. Some operators have higher precedence then others. This will result in “2+3*4” = 14 and not =10. “*” has an higher precedence as “+”. So, first the multiplication is done and then the addition. You could write also “2+ (3*4)”. That is completely the same.

Next property is the associativity. If the precedence is equal, then the associativity will decide, in what sequence an expression will be evaluated. The associativity is “left” or “right”. And this means, the operand is evaluated from left to right or from right to left.

In the CPP reference, [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), there is a very good description. Please read this. And if we analyze this then we will see that the comparison operator `==` has a higher precedence than the logical `or`. So, we can already rewrite the expression as:

```
(text.at(i) == 'a')     || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u' || 'y'
```

The following logical `or` operators have the same precedence. Then, the associativity will decide, in which sequence the are evaluated: From left to write. So, we can rewrite the expression now to

```
((text.at(i) == 'a')   || 'e')   || 'i' || 'o' || 'u' || 'y'     // then
(((text.at(i) == 'a')   || 'e')  || 'i' )  || 'o' || 'u' || 'y'     // then
((((text.at(i) == 'a')   || 'e')  || 'i' )  || 'o' )  || 'u' || 'y'     // then finally
(((((text.at(i) == 'a')   || 'e')  || 'i' )  || 'o' )  || 'u' )  || 'y'
```

OK, next we need to understand the character literals, like ‘a’ or ‘e’ have values. Often they are encoded with the ASCII. Then ‘a’ has the value 97 and ‘e’ has the value 101 and so on. You may look in an ASCII table. But how can such values be interpreted as Boolean `true` or `false`? Simple: C++ treats 0 as `false` and all other values as true.

Additionally, you need to learn about Boolean short-circuit evaluation. Please read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical)

This means: If the result is already clear, then no further operation will be performed. For example. If `( text.at(i) == 'a')`, so, if the letter is really ‘a’, then the result is true. No further operation will be done. Easy. If not, then the expression would result in:

```
(((((false)  || 'e')  || 'i' )  || 'o' )  || 'u' )  || 'y'
```

Then, the evaluation will be `false || ‘e’`. and ‘e’ is equal to 101, resulting in: `false||101`. And this is always true. End of evaluation. Nothing more will be done. The result is either true, because a letter is ‘a’ or anyway. This is called a tautology: Always true. And hence, all characters are printed.

And, our friend, the compiler with all warnings enabled, or static code analysis, will find this problem and inform us.

---

I saw in another answer the example something like `std::cout << 97 || 101 || 105 || 111 || 117 || 121;` My guess is that the author does not understand fully what it means. Here the inserter operator `<<` has a higher precedence than the logical or operator ||`. You can also rewrite this to:

```
(((((std::cout << 97)  ||  101 )  || 105 )  || 111 )   || 117 )   || 121;
```

As you can see. First we will write the number 97 to `std::cout` The inserter operator will always return a reference to the stream, for which it was called. So, next we have:

```
((((std::cout  ||  101 )  || 105 )  || 111 )   || 117 )   || 121;
```

Now, `std::cout` is used in a Boolean expression. And guess what? `std::cout`has a bool operator (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool)). And this will return `true` if everything was OK. And since everything is OK for writing something to `std::cout`, the short circuit evaluation will kick in, and no further operation is executed. The resulting statement would be the same as writing ‘true;’ in a line. The output is only a side effect of the evaluation of the boolean expression. But this was just a side note.

---

What we learn from that. We should really understand the expressions that we are writing. And, a very important recommendation: Use brackets, even if redundant. Always use many brackets to make it clear what you mean. You would have recognized the error by yourself, if you would have used brackets.

Isn’t it astonishing, how many explanations are necessary to analyze such a simple statement? But now we understand and can work on the solution.

---

### Recommended solution

In order to compare a letter with all of the vowels ‘a’, ‘e’, ‘I’, ‘o’, ‘u’ and so on, we need to compare the letter with all of the vowels ‘a’, ‘e’, ‘I’, ‘o’, ‘u’ and so on. Yes. That is it:

```
if (   (text.at(i) == 'a') || (text.at(i) == 'e') || (text.at(i) == 'i') || (text.at(i) == 'o') || (text.at(i) == 'u')  ) . . .
```

BTW, the letter ‘y’ is not considered as a vowel. Anyway. You can search what you want.

---

Additionally, there are many many different solutions possible.

Some are faster than others, some or more intuitive, some require less typing work and whatever.

The 2 solutions shown in the other answers, by using a `std::set` and `find` or a `std::array` together with `std::find` are not the fastest solutions.

In the case of the `std::set`, a `std::unordered_set` together with its `count` function would be more efficient and faster, because the `std::unordered_set` uses fast hasing algorithms for searching. And `std::find` can also be outperformed by a simple calculation. This I will show in the end.

If you prefer something more readable (and maybe know other languages) you can model an `in`-like operation, for example:

```
if (5, in{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }) . . .
```

But for this you need to do some really advance stuff. I just want to show you here what is possible. As I said, there are many many different possible solutions. For the above statement we would need to additionally define some wrapper class for a `std::initializer_list` and overload its comma operator. As, I said, some heavy stuff:

```
template<class T>
struct in {
    in(const std::initializer_list<T>& il) : ref(il) {}
    const std::initializer_list<T>& ref;
};

template<class T>
bool operator,(const T& lhs, const is_in<T>& rhs) {
    return std::find(rhs.ref.begin(), rhs.ref.end(), lhs) != rhs.ref.end();
}
```

Forget it for now.

---

Now, last but not least, the fastest possible solution for alpha ASCII letters. The `if`-statement:

```
if ( 0x02208222 >> (text.at[i] & 0x1f)) & 1) . . .
```

Will give you what you need. We have here only a fast bitwise-and then a bitwise-shift and again a bitwise-and. This can be evaluated superfast.

But how the hack?

This know how is very very old and was used in ancient times, when people were working with assembler on their 8 bit microcontrollers. We rely on ASCII for alpha letters and on the inventors, who made some smart decisions when defining the code.

Please see the below picture.
[image]
If you look at the uppercase alpha letters and the lowercase alpha letters, then you can see that only the first 5 bits are important to encode any apha letter. That is clear, because with 5 bits you can encode values between 0..31. And we have only 26 alpha letters in western languages. The bit number 5 (the sixth bit, counting starts with 0) decides, about the case. A set bit number 5 means lowercase. This you can clearly see in the tables. And because of that, the delta between a lowercase alpha letter and an uppercase alpha letter is always 32. In binary a number with bit number 5 (the sixth bit, counting starts with 0) set. And, if we want to ignore the case, then we make a bitwise-and (masking) with `0001 1111`b which is `0x1f`hex and we get a number equivalents from 1 to 26 for the letters ‘A’ – ‘Z’ for any case. That is for the part `text.at[i] & 0x1f`. Aha.

The next smart idea is to encode alpha letters that we want to search in bit positions. For example. We take a 32bit unsigned integer value. In this value, we set the bit according to the number that the letter has. If we search for example for an ‘a’, then we see that ‘a’ has an associated number 1, and we set the bit number 1 (the 2nd bit, counting starts with 0). If we additionally look for an ‘e’ we set the bit number 5 (the sixth bit, counting starts with 0) in our value. And for whichever alpha character we want to search, we set the corresponding bit in our 32 bit unsigned int value.

After we did this for all the alpha letters that you are searching for, we get the resulting number `0x02208222` hex. Aha. Now we know, here this is coming from. And if we want to check now for a certain alpha letter, then we shift the bits in this number so many positions to the right as its corresponding alpha letter equivalent indicates. And if we find then a set bit at the lowest possible position, then we have a positive match.

Complicated, but cool. Finds all possible sets of alpha letters ultra-fast.

But I admit, you need to think about that . . .

---

So, I hope you I could give you a somehow understandable explanation. If there are questions open, then please ask.

---

.

---

Benchmark

---

To compare different solutions, I added a benchmark. The result is remarkable. I run the test 3 times with 1 Billion random test cases.

Resulting Ranking:

```
1. ASCII approach       100%
2. Unordered_set        395%
3. Standard comparison  522%
4. constexpr array     1046% 
5. set                 1638%
```

Implementation of Benchmark:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <set>

constexpr size_t TestDataSize = 1'000'000'000u;
constexpr size_t NumberOfTestRuns = 3u;
using TestData = std::array<char, TestDataSize>;

const char SourceCharacter[]{"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"};

TestData testData;


bool isVowel_ASCII(const char c) {
    return (0x02208222 >> (c & 0x1f)) & 1;
}

static constexpr std::array<char, 12> vowels{ 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y', 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y' };
bool isVowel_ConstexprArray(const char c) {
    return (std::end(vowels) != std::find(begin(vowels),
        end(vowels), c));
}

const std::unordered_set<char> vowel_UnorderedSet{ 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y', 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y' };
bool isVowel_UnorderedSet(const char c) {
    return vowel_UnorderedSet.count(c);
}


const std::set<char> vowel_Set{ 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y', 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y' };
bool isVowel_Set(const char c) {
    return (vowel_Set.find(c) != vowel_Set.end());;
}

bool isVowel_Standard(const char c) {
    return (c == 'a') || (c == 'e') || (c == 'i') || (c == 'o') || (c == 'u') || (c == 'y') ||
        (c == 'A') || (c == 'E') || (c == 'I') || (c == 'O') || (c == 'U') || (c == 'Y') ;
}

int main() {

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 generator(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> intRange(0, sizeof(SourceCharacter)-1);


    size_t counter_ASCII{};
    size_t counter_ConstexprArray{};
    size_t counter_UnorderedSet{};
    size_t counter_Set{};
    size_t counter_Standard{};

    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start);


    for (size_t testRun{}; testRun < NumberOfTestRuns; ++testRun) {

        std::cout << "\n\n\nTest run " << (testRun + 1) << "\n\n";

        std::generate(testData.begin(), testData.end(), [&]() {return SourceCharacter[intRange(generator)]; });

        counter_ASCII = 0u;
        counter_ConstexprArray = 0u;
        counter_UnorderedSet = 0u;
        counter_Set = 0u;
        counter_Standard = 0;

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

        for (size_t testCase{}; testCase < TestDataSize; ++testCase) {
            if (isVowel_ASCII(testData[testCase])) ++counter_ASCII;
        }

        elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start);
        std::cout << "Test 'ASCII` solution. Resulting vowel count:           " << counter_ASCII << "\t Duration: " << elapsed.count() << " ms\n";

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

        for (size_t testCase{}; testCase < TestDataSize; ++testCase) {
            if (isVowel_UnorderedSet(testData[testCase])) ++counter_UnorderedSet;
        }

        elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start);
        std::cout << "Test 'unordered_set' solution. Resulting vowel count:   " << counter_UnorderedSet << "\t Duration: " << elapsed.count() << " ms\n";

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

        for (size_t testCase{}; testCase < TestDataSize; ++testCase) {
            if (isVowel_Standard(testData[testCase])) ++counter_Standard;
        }

        elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start);
        std::cout << "Test 'standard' solution. Resulting vowel count:        " << counter_Standard << "\t Duration: " << elapsed.count() << " ms\n";


        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

        for (size_t testCase{}; testCase < TestDataSize; ++testCase) {
            if (isVowel_ConstexprArray(testData[testCase])) ++counter_ConstexprArray;
        }

        elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start);
        std::cout << "Test 'Constexpr array` solution. Resulting vowel count: " << counter_ConstexprArray << "\t Duration: " << elapsed.count() << " ms\n";


        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

        for (size_t testCase{}; testCase < TestDataSize; ++testCase) {
            if (isVowel_Set(testData[testCase])) ++counter_Set;
        }

        elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start);
        std::cout << "Test 'set' solution. Resulting vowel count:             " << counter_Set << "\t Duration: " << elapsed.count() << " ms\n";

    }
}
```

(compiled with optimizations on)

Result:

```
Test run 1

Test 'ASCII` solution. Resulting vowel count:           226384481        Duration: 920 ms
Test 'unordered_set' solution. Resulting vowel count:   226384481        Duration: 3630 ms
Test 'standard' solution. Resulting vowel count:        226384481        Duration: 4780 ms
Test 'Constexpr array` solution. Resulting vowel count: 226384481        Duration: 9620 ms
Test 'set' solution. Resulting vowel count:             226384481        Duration: 15060 ms



Test run 2

Test 'ASCII` solution. Resulting vowel count:           226421607        Duration: 920 ms
Test 'unordered_set' solution. Resulting vowel count:   226421607        Duration: 3630 ms
Test 'standard' solution. Resulting vowel count:        226421607        Duration: 4800 ms
Test 'Constexpr array` solution. Resulting vowel count: 226421607        Duration: 9650 ms
Test 'set' solution. Resulting vowel count:             226421607        Duration: 15060 ms



Test run 3

Test 'ASCII` solution. Resulting vowel count:           226416438        Duration: 920 ms
Test 'unordered_set' solution. Resulting vowel count:   226416438        Duration: 3630 ms
Test 'standard' solution. Resulting vowel count:        226416438        Duration: 4800 ms
Test 'Constexpr array` solution. Resulting vowel count: 226416438        Duration: 9620 ms
Test 'set' solution. Resulting vowel count:             226416438        Duration: 15070 ms
```

---

As expected.

- The ASCII solution is the fastest. It was designed for that prupose. But it is for alpha ASCII letters only, not that compatible, not easy to understand and not that readable . . .
- The `std::unordered_set` is ultrafast, easy to read and understand and is hence *the idiomatic correct approach*
- The naive approach by comparing against all vowels, is astonishing fast. Never understimate an otimizing compiler . . .

@OP Please use the recommended solution

Comment: One disadvantage of the ASCII algorithm is that it also detects !, %, ), /, 5, 9 as vowels

Comment: '&& ((c & 0xc0) == 0x40)' could be added, but would slow it down ...

Answer (score 2):

Consider using range based for loops, example here :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

// dont use : using namespace std; this will bite you in larger projects.

// make small functions that you can reuse/make code more readable
bool is_vowel(const char c)
{
    // create a set of vowels.
    // by making the set static it is only initialized once on the first call
    // by using a set the final code will contain less if/then checks
    static const std::set<char> vowels{ 'a','e','i','o','u', 'A','E','I','O','U' };

    // return if character is found in set
    return (vowels.find(c) != vowels.end());
    // C+20 return vowels.contains(c);
}

void print_vowels(const std::string word)
{
    std::cout << "the vowels for word " << word << " are : ";

    // this is a range based for loop
    // it will loop over all items in a collection (something with begin() and end() methods.
    // it has one big benefit, it will not go out of bounds (indices can)
    for (const char c : word)
    {
        // check with the function written earlier
        // this makes code much more readable.
        if (is_vowel(c)) std::cout << c;
    }

    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    print_vowels("banana");
    print_vowels("himalaya");
    print_vowels("pinguin");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you mind answering why "using namespace std;" isn't recommended? I only use it so I don't need to type out "std::" everytime

Comment: Get used to typing namespaces https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/2-9-naming-collisions-and-an-introduction-to-namespaces/ :) Also this link should explain a lot : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice. My advice : never try to save on typing work. Typing that you only do once (and isn't even the most work of coding), reading code back is done more often (by you or others that need to maintain code)

Comment: @PepijnKramer You could consider to better use a `std::unordered_set` together with the `count` function. IMHO this would be the iodiomatic correct approach. You may also check my answer for even faster solutions. But, as always, there are many many different possible solutions and yours is good. There will be no noticeable difference in speed . . .

Comment: @ArminMontigny I usually go for readability first (comes with years and years of maintaining code too), and worry about speed optimization later. And sure I will think about performance of the selected datastructure. I just didn't think about unordered_set this time so thanks about the heads up :)

Comment: @PepijnKramer. Some additional info. I added a benchmark at the bottom. Very interesting is, how fast the naive approach is. I am really surprised . . .

Comment: Hehe yes :) Goes to show, when optimizing always measure. Two things that help I think are data locality>The characters to compare against are in the code segment and are already cached, and branch prediction kicking in since it can always asume the false branch will be taken 1 in 52 chance of being wrong. Add to that the compiler that can reorder generated code to make full use of the branch prediction and off we go :)

Comment: @ArminMontigny Oh and thanks, I always find those kind of benchmarks quite interesting :)

Answer (score 2):

If you run the following line :

```
cout << 'a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u' || 'y' ;
```

you will get the output as **'a'** .
The previous line essentially performs like this:

```
cout << 97 || 101 || 105 || 111 || 117 || 121 ; // this gives 97
```

The reason your code performs like that is because there is a corresponding ASCII value for each character and by this line you are only attempting to do the **OR** operation on bunch of integers or numeric values(ASCII value) under the hood. So you cannot expect this line to work like it should. Instead you have to individually check the condition like:

```
if (text[i] == 'a' || text[i] == 'e' || text[i] == 'i' || text[i] == 'o' || text[i] == 'u' || text[i] == 'y') 
{ 
cout << text[i]; 
}
```

Like stated above, you can check the ASCII value of a certain character by:

```
char c = 'a';
cout << "ASCII Value of " << c << " is " << int(c);
```

The program basically compares the integers(the ASCII value) and based on that it can tell whether it is a vowel or not. As long as we do **OR** operation between two or more integers we are always getting a `true` value because these integers are essentially non-zero values. Doing **OR** operation between two or more non-zero values will always return a `true`.

I would recommend to use the `[]` operator for better performance so use `text[i]` instead of `text.at(i)`

Comment: I was also thinking, what if I want to create another subprogram that types out the constants in the inputted word? Do I need to do the same thing for every single letter in the alphabet (except the vowels)? Isn't there a faster way to do it?

Like looping through the entire alphabet and if it isn't a vowel, you type out a constant.

Comment: of course, the clever way is to choose the loop otherwise it will take 2077 to complete writing the program

Comment: @MohamedAlkalam: You could write a function `bool isVowel(char c)` and then write `bool isConsonant(char c) { return std::isalpha(c) && ! isVowel(c); `

Comment: Just a guess, it might perhaps be that you do not fully get all implications of your statement `cout << 97 || 101 || 105 || 111 || 117 || 121 ;` I analyzed this in depth in my answer. But your answer is also absolutely correct and very good!